# Tracking memory problems

Tags: memory, performance-monitoring, memory-usage, perfmon, remote-access

I'm experiencing some trouble with my Windows Server 2008. We're using it for hosting a bunch (~50) of Web GIS applications on IIS.

This setup usually works very well, but when certain applications have certain setups, a leak occurs, and the server cannot be accessed until the application pool or the server is restarted.

I'm wondering how I can find the culprit, and it seems that **perfmon** is a good bet. If I want to connect perfmon to my server, which is outside my domain, what is required to do it?

Also, are there any other (and/or better) tools to connect remotely and see what process that is taking up all the servers memory?

Comment: Can you not just run it locally on the server by RDPing to it?

Comment: As I wrote, the server cannot be accessed (via RDP - http works fine) until the application pool or server is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a standard scenario for any decent monitoring application. If the leak is that serious that it requires a restart of the server, then I suspect that the Nonpaged pool is filling up all available RAM at that point. That's a performance counter you can measure (Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes) and get alerted when it goes over a limit.

I don't think there is a whole lot you can do with Windows itself to detect this and/or take corrective action, although you could try to setup a trigger in Performance Monitor that would automatically reboot the server.

Is a scheduled restart of IIS an option?

Failing all these, we offer a free third-party software called [EventSentry Light](http://www.eventsentry.com) which can automatically detect leaks in performance counters (e.g. the memory usage keeps going up) and then trigger a reboot (e.g. if the values gets over a certain threshold). The commercial version of EventSentry also collects performance data which can then be reviewed with web-based reporting.